# Custom django admin template for app

Tags: python, django, backend, django-1.6

I would like to create a custom index.html derived from the admin/index.html individual for each app in my django project.

For instance my folder structure is like:

- app1

  - templates

    - index.html (different from the global template admin/index.html)
- app2
- templates

  - admin

    - base.html
    - index.html (global template index.html)

How can I achieve custom admin index.html files for my apps, that are recognized by django? For the moment only the index.html in the global template/admin folder is considered for rendering the index pages in my backend.

I'm using django 1.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, only certain parts of the Django admin site can be overridden on a per-app basis, as it says in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#templates-which-may-be-overridden-per-app-or-model):

> Not every template in contrib/admin/templates/admin may be overridden per app or per model. The following can:
>
> - app_index.html
> - change_form.html
> - change_list.html
> - delete_confirmation.html
> - object_history.html

Remember that the admin interface is *itself* and app, so it's going to do a single template sweep and load the first set of templates that comes up.

I think your two best bets are either to [use multiple admin sites in your project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#multiple-admin-sites-in-the-same-urlconf) or to [add a custom view for specific apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites) -- the former is probably easier, but will be a problem if you don't want people to have to login separately to control certain things.

Comment: Even by using modifiable templates in my apps it is pretty odd, that for instance a admin-template in app1 is not considdered if the entry for the template directory in TEMPLATE_DIRS is listed after the template directory of app2.
Django does not seem to distinguish between the apps by rendering admin templates at all, or am I wrong here?

Comment: This could be due to a few things.  First, you need to make sure that the template is in an admin folder, like app1/templates/admin/index.html, whereas those templates for the app itself should be app1/templates/app1/whatever_template. Like any other app, the django admin interface is going to look for a namespaced folder, and skip over anything that isn't properly namespaced.

Comment: I'm confused. The namespacing for admin does not seem to work for me. If I apply my structure like:

- app1/templates/admin/app_index.html
- app2/templates/admin/app_index.html

does not seem to work. So neither the app2/templates/admin/app_index.html nor app/.../app_index.html does not seem to be considered.

Comment: Ok, I see now, that ALL my app-Admin changes have to be in the global templates/admin/( app1 | app2 )/ directory to work for each app.